# Go OAuth1 with different keys

Tags: go, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am developing an application that uses an API that requires OAuth1.0. I have a list of API keys (access token, access token secret, consumer key and consumer secret). I would like to update the OAuth used by the http client whenever I want.

This is how I achieved it in Python

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1


oauth_credentials = [
    {
        "access_token": "a",
        "access_token_secret": "b",
        "consumer_key": "c",
        "consumer_secret": "d"
    },
    {
        "access_token": "a",
        "access_token_secret": "b",
        "consumer_key": "c",
        "consumer_secret": "d"
    },
    ...
]

oauths = [OAuth1(client_key=oauth_cred["consumer_key"], client_secret=oauth_cred["consumer_secret"], resource_owner_key=oauth_cred["access_token"], resource_owner_secret=oauth_cred["access_token_secret"]) for oauth_cred in oauth_credentials]

session = requests.Session()

i = 0
session.auth = oauths[i]
```

I can't figure out how to achieve this efficiently in Go. The closest I have come is using https://github.com/dghubble/oauth1. However, in their example they create a new httpClient for each set of credentials like

```
config := oauth1.NewConfig("consumerKey", "consumerSecret")
token := oauth1.NewToken("token", "tokenSecret")

// httpClient will automatically authorize http.Request's
httpClient := config.Client(oauth1.NoContext, token)
```

Would it be equivalent to store a list of http clients?

I should note that I am trying to maximise runtime efficiency at the cost of setup processing, so establishing these before running each request is important.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using an [auth1 client](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/oauth1/oauth) that does not require an http client per set of credentials.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I don't understand how that helps? I'm not familar enough with Go to implement that myself in the way I described with no examples.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Please could you show me an example?